# Generic type declaration caused an error

Tags: java, generics

To be brief, I have:

```
public interface Dictionary<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Iterable<E> {
```

And

```
public class TreeDictionary implements Dictionary<TreeDictionary> {
```

When compiled, caused an error

> TreeDictionary.java:4: type parameter TreeDictionary is not within its
>   bound public class TreeDictionary implements
>   Dictionary {

I guess the reason is probably because I'm not fully clear with the declaration of the Dictionary interface.

Would really appreciate if somebody could explain me this :)

Comment: Your `TreeDictionary` class does not implements `Comparable` interface. Check if you really want that TreeDictionary implements a Dictionary of TreeDictionary (again)

Comment: Are you sure that you want `TreeDictionary` to be a `Dictionary` of `TreeDictionary`s?

Comment: @trutheality: If it's a tree structure, then yes, probably.

Comment: @skaffman I was thinking that the "tree" prefix is serving the same purpose as the "tree" in `TreeMap`, but I see how it would make sense under your interpretation.

Comment: for best results, use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Dictionary<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

That says that whichever type you want to use for `E`, it must implement the `Comparable` interface.

Given your`TreeDictionary` definition:

```
public class TreeDictionary implements Dictionary<TreeDictionary>
```

`TreeDictionary` does not implement `Comparable`, and so cannot be substituted for `E` in the generic type of `Dictionary`.

Try this instead:

```
public class TreeDictionary implements Dictionary<TreeDictionary>, Comparable<TreeDictionary>
```

`TreeDictionary` should now conform to the constraints of `E`.

Answer (score 0):

Your TreeDictionary class should also implement the Comaparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement Comparable interface for it to work

public class TreeDictionary implements Dictionary, Comparable

hope it helps